# How do I send a custom HTTP header with Active HTTP Health Checks in NGINX Plus

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am trying to use NGINX Plus as a load balancer for several backends and I want to use the HTTP Health Check feature of NGINX Plus, to ensure that all backends are available and able to serve requests. However the backend is propriety software, which requires a custom HTTP header to be present in requests to the health check endpoints. How do I configure NGINX Plus to add a custom HTTP header to health check requests sent to the backends? https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/http-health-check/ only shows how to configure HTTP Health Check but not how to add custom HTTP headers to the health checks.